# Python psutil module, why does it end up with an exception when i call .exe() method before an if statement

Tags: python, psutil

I'm working on a project that requires me using `psutil`, I was trying to compare some values to that of a `.txt` file's but for some reason whenever I called the `psutil.Procces.exe()` method outside an if statement it'd end up with an Access Denied exception, let me show you what I mean:

```
import psutil
import time

ini = 'start'

def getTaskList():
    list_of_ran_proccesses = []
    for procs in psutil.process_iter():
        list_of_ran_proccesses.append(procs)
    return list_of_ran_proccesses

def CompareRunningFiles():
    if ini == "start":
        list_of_old_procs = getTaskList()
        while list_of_old_procs == getTaskList():
            time.sleep(0.01)
        for new_procs in psutil.process_iter():
            if not new_procs in list_of_old_procs:
                print(new_procs.exe())  

CompareRunningFiles()
```

This example works completely fine but if i do this

```
import psutil
import time

ini = 'start'

def getTaskList():
    list_of_ran_proccesses = []
    for procs in psutil.process_iter():
        list_of_ran_proccesses.append(procs)
    return list_of_ran_proccesses

def CompareRunningFiles():
    if ini == "start":
        list_of_old_procs = getTaskList()
        while list_of_old_procs == getTaskList():
            time.sleep(0.01)
        for new_procs in psutil.process_iter():
            print(new_procs.exe())

CompareRunningFiles()
```

This for some reason ends up with an Access Denied exception.
Thank you for all your answers :)

**Edit:** I'm not sure but, can this be because the module is trying to access some protected directories?

Because after the if statement it would only try to get the directory of whatever process was launched but without the if statement it'd try and access all sorts of running processes.

So when it comes across a system process, it'd try and get it's directory too, which if the process runs inside a protected directory it would raise an Access Denied exception.

Comment: You cannot access the `.exe()` property of processes that you don't have permission for. If you run as administrator, it should work. You can also `try ... except psutil.AccessDenied: pass` to skip those problematic processes. Note that in your second example you will print ALL currently running processes, not just new ones. In your first example you have a race condition where a process gets created and then immediately deleted between the second getTaskList() call and the psutil.process_iter() call, the process list might change between those calls.

Comment: @Omer Thank you for the very quick answer ! i kinda figured it out after asking the question but your explanation made everything clearer, thank you ! Also i tried running it as administrator but some protected Windows directories would still cause some problems, the try/except method seems very efficent in solving this issue.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit; your question should remain strictly a question. If you don'tedelete it and Omer doesn't post his comment as a proper answer, you might want to post an answer of your own, and accept that. (Maybe mark it "community wiki" to not claim any reputation for yourself.)

Comment: @tripleee I'm sorry, i didn't realise it was the comments section, pretty new to this site. I'll do just what you told me, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the if statement there prevents the program from trying to get the directory of some system processes(They are always on), some directories in Windows are protected and cannot be accessed directly which, without the if statement the module is trying to get the directories of all running processes and this causes an exception when it tries to do that for a process that's running from a protected directory (example: System Idle Process), using (as Omer said) a "try:... except psutil.AccessDenied: pass" will skip those processes and prevent this issue. Thank you Omer for the explanation and tripleee for the same :D